# Pandas to_csv write json objects with no spaces

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I have a dataframe object with some columns of type dict, containing some nested json objects. When I use to_csv to write the dataframe to a csv file, everything works, however the json objects have spaces for formatting in them, like:

`{'field': 'value', 'field2': 'value2'}`

I want to write to csv but remove the extra spaces, to preserve space, similarly to the result from:

`json.dumps(obj, separators=(':',''))`

So the output looks like:

`{'field':'value','field2':'value2'}`

How can I achieve this with a dataframe? Or control somehow the formatting of the specific json columns?

Comment: That is not JSON, `to_csv` doesn't automatically emit JSON

Comment: Please [edit] your question with some *actual* sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to export your data without extra spaces, you can convert your dictionary as string and replace `': '` with `':'`:

```
# or better all extra spaces?
>>> df.assign(A=df['A'].astype(str).str.replace(r'([:,]) ', r'\1', regex=True))

                                      A
0  {'field':'value1','field2':'value2'}
1  {'field':'value3','field2':'value4'}
```

To export as json, you can replace `.astype(str)` with `.map(json.dumps)`:

```
# import json
>>> df.assign(A=df['A'].map(json.dumps).str.replace(r'([:,]) ', r'\1', regex=True))

                                      A
0  {"field":"value1","field2":"value2"}
1  {"field":"value3","field2":"value4"}
```

Minimal Working Example:

```
import pandas as pd

obj = [{'field': 'value1', 'field2': 'value2'},
       {'field': 'value3', 'field2': 'value4'}]
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': obj})
print(df)

# Output
                                         A
0  {'field': 'value1', 'field2': 'value2'}
1  {'field': 'value3', 'field2': 'value4'}
```